# If statement into useEffect hooks - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-effect

I am reviewing my code and i see that since i started using react hooks i had some "issue" i cannot say , but it is not clean enough . So basically i want to clean a little bit my approach to the issue . I want to use an `if` statement inside of `useEffect` and also inside of `setSomething()` .
So basically there is one message that i want to display regarding on the state conditions .

**Current :**

```
const [displayFeedbackMessage, setDisplayFeedbackMessage ] = useState(undefined);
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {

        setDisplayFeedbackMessage(
            <div>
            {
                displaySelectionResult &&
                selected > 0 &&
                <div className={classes.dnaTableFeedbackMessageDiv}>
                   <b>{Pluralize("document", selected, true)}</b>
                    {" "}selected out of{" "}
                    <b>{Pluralize("document", available, true)}</b>
                    {" "}available.
                </div>
            }

            {
                displayActionResult &&
                <div className={classes.dnaTableFeedbackMessageDiv}>
                    <b>{Pluralize("document", actioned, true)}</b>
                    {" "} downloaded out of{" "}
                    <b>{Pluralize("document", requested, true)}</b>
                    {" "}requested.
                </div>
            }
            </div>
        )

},[selected, displaySelectionResult, displayActionResult])
```

...

```
return (

               <Paper>{displayFeedbackMessage}</Paper>
)
```

It works fine without any issues . But when i try to switch it as this :

**Expectation :**

```
useEffect(() => {

        setDisplayFeedbackMessage(
            if(displaySelectionResult && selected > 0) {
              <b>{Pluralize("document", selected, true)}</b>
              {" "}selected out of{" "}
              <b>{Pluralize("document", available, true)}</b>
              {" "}available.

        } else if (displayActionResult) {
              <b>{Pluralize("document", actioned, true)}</b>
              {" "} downloaded out of{" "}
              <b>{Pluralize("document", requested, true)}</b>
              {" "}requested.
      }
)
},[selected, displaySelectionResult, displayActionResult])
```

The conclusion is that i want to reduce the `jsx` expression inside of my `useEffect` , but it seems to that it is not working . Can someone give me a hand and tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: `if-else` statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.

Comment: maybe you could set both these JSX as two different variables and then use it with the condition? also put the condition outside of `setDisplayFeedbackMessage`. You might need to use `Fragment` around those JSX blocks

Comment: I would not store the JSX inside the state, just store the data needed inside the state and return depending on that state, this makes it a lot more readable, and indeed as the comment above you need to wrap the JSX in fragments like this: <>{your JSX}</>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `useEffect` hook. The problem is that you are creating an `if` statement directly in your `setState` value.

`setState` expects a callback so that won't work. You could achieve the desired result by passing in a callback with an if-statement though:

```
setState(() => {
  if (condition) {
    return something;
  }

  return somethingElse
})
```

Comment: Actually you are right so stupid of me i was missing the `return` statement . When it is added it works like a charm . Thanks mate !

Comment: Glad I could help ;)